# How to check if files exists on a folder?

Tags: php

I want to know how to check if is there any files on a given folder without knowing the names of the files present on the folder,

I am not looking for a specefic file, but I want a function that returns to me 'true' if there is one or many files on the folder, or 'false' if there is no files on the folder.

Comment: Please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: use `file_exists('path_to_file')`; it return true if file exists else returns false...

Comment: What about `glob();` ?

Comment: file_exists is not what I need, because I don't know the name of the files before.

Comment: Maybe scandir() can resolve the problem if I test the size of $array = scandir($my_folder);